# Is it possible to execute a php file in Amazon EC2(Elastic Compute Cloud)?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

Can you share code snippets to execute a PHP file in Amazon EC2.

Comment: Can you please provide more information if none of the answers below are correct, or accept one of the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

there's nothing special about PHP in EC2.  you need to have a instance with PHP installed and configured for your particular use case (CLI, apache module, FastCGI), just as with physical machines.

Answer (score 1):

How do you mean execute a php file?

Within Amazon EC2, just create a Ubuntu instance, install apache + php, upload your php file to the instance and place it in apache (the same as if it were any other web server).

Browse to the file location from your browser and it will run, just as any other php file would.

Answer (score 0):

Amazone instance is nothing but a hosting space. You should have PHP/Mysql enabled (If you purchase a server space for PHP.). Just push the file to server and run it.

If it is not enabled by default, install LAMP.